# how to make a container's width and height based on its child whether it is inside listview.builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have just created a simple container, its working fine with all parent widget but when i place it inside listview.builder, container's width increase to maximum width,

is there any way to keep container width based on its child text width?

```
class CustomContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomContainer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Text('I am demo Text',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,fontSize: 20,color: Colors.white),),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shrinkWrap: true` same as below

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Listview.builder(
         shrinkWrap: true,
         itemCount: ......
      );
  }
```